# Exchange Calendar syncing issue on Maverics

Tags: macos, calendar, exchange

I have an Exchange calendar synced with Mavericks' Calendar app. I've changed time of one event. Since that a window with following message appears over and over:

> Calendar can’t delete an occurrence from the repeating the event
>   “[event]” from the Exchange server.

I've tried to re-add the calendar as well as the whole Exchange account. Deleting the `Calendar Cache*` files (in `~/Library/Calendars`) screws up all calendar data and I'm not able to re-add the synced calendars.

I've all calendars synced in cloud (iCloud, Google, Exchange), so deleting the Calendar files is no issue.

Comment: It says it is a "Repeating" event !

Comment: Yes, it is. Only one event of this series was changed. Does this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trial and error, these actions finally solved this issue:

1. Delete Exchange account from Internet Accounts in System Settings
2. Clean User and System cache with Onyx
3. Restart Computer
4. Re-add the Exchange account

Tested on MacOS 10.9.4.